# How to extract SMSes from a non rooted device with a broken touchscreen?

Tags: sms, touchscreen, htc-wildfire-s

I have an [HTC Wildfire S A510e](http://www.gsmarena.com/htc_wildfire_s-3777.php) (Android 2.3.5, not rooted). I want to extract my SMS messages and import them into another device.

## Problems:

- There is no free space on the internal memory left. No apps such as SMS backup can be installed.
- The touchscreen is broken, I cannot unlock the display or use any buttons (e.g. home, back, search).
- Device is not rooted. I cannot view the contents of `/data/` and thus can't use `adb uninstall` to free up space.

The SMS-database is located in:

```
/data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db
```

`ls -l` outputs:

```
-rw-rw---- radio    radio      977920 2013-03-12 10:12 mmssms.db
```

However, `adb pull mmssms.db` or `cat mmssms.db` don't work (Permission denied).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't have any good ideas myself, I can help yours, though. 1) You don't need to be rooted to use "adb uninstall <package>". Use "adb shell pm list packages -f" to see what's installed, then use adb uninstall on the non-system stuff listed. 2) You also seem to be using adb pull wrong. It needs the full path. "adb pull /data/data/com.android.providers.telephony/databases/mmssms.db" run from your desktop, not run from adb shell. Although that DB may or may not be world readable. So the command may still fail. *) I guess I would write an app to pull the messages by API and run it from Eclipse.